# A conceptual question about a converging or diverging series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

When you are testing for convergence or divergence by integration f(x), which models A sub n, why does f(x) have to be positive for all x on your interval? For an example, after taking the limit of A sub n to infinity and getting zero,  wouldn't the integration test yield an accurate result if f(x) is rather monotonically increasing for your interval and it is negative (which you should typically be able to manipulate so that it is) rather than decreasing and being positive, then shouldn't the integration test suffice that inquiry? Thanks.

Comment: if you think of it visually, then i guess you might be right. What if you take your negative $f(x)$, define $g(x) \,=\,-f(x)$, and plug $g(x)$ into the test? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Are you referring to the Integral Test For Convergence? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Comment: Yes, the rule is that is f(x) is always decreasing and positive, then you can use the integral test for convergence. What i'm wondering is, what if my sequence is always negative and always increasing? Shouldn't I able able to find convergence in that manner as well?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, you can. But the integral test for convergence specifically requires an always positive decreasing function. So we require a bit more reasoning as of why this is okay.

Firstly,

$${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \text{ converges iff } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-a_n\text{ converges}}$$

And

$${\int_{1}^{\infty}f(n) dn\text{ converges iff } \int_{1}^{\infty}-f(n)dn\text{ converges}}$$

Since your function ${f(x)}$ is always negative and increasing, then ${-f(x)}$ is always positive and decreasing, and so the integral test can be applied to ${-f(x)}$. So overall

$${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \text{ converges iff } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-a_n \text{ converges iff } \int_{1}^{\infty}-f(n)dn \text{ converges iff } \int_{1}^{\infty}f(n)dn \text{ converges}}$$

And there is what we wanted to show:

$${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \text{ converges iff } \int_{1}^{\infty}f(n)dn \text{ converges} }$$